# JavaScript Object Question

Tags: javascript, object

What I want to do with the fs object is to add multiple "items" to the fs.items property.
How can I do this? You can see my attempt below, obviously this does not work.

I am a beginner, go easy on me :)

Thanks...

```
var fs = {
    name:'test',
    items:[]
};

fs.items = {
    name:'item1',
    value:1
};

fs.items = {
    name:'item2',
    value:2
}
```

Comment: Philippe has it - as for your solution, what you're actually doing is reassigning the items property each time.

Answer (score 10):

You could use "push":

```
fs.items.push( { 
    name:'item1',
    value:1
});

fs.items.push( {
    name:'item2',
    value:2
});
```

The [push()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_push.asp) function will add entries to an existing array

Answer (score 1):

```
fs.items.push('item1', 'item2'); // fs.items is now ['item1', 'item2']
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add an entry to an array, you have to use `.push` or `item[...]`

```
fs.items.push( {
    name:'item1',
    value:1
});

fs.items['item2'] = {
    name:'item2',
    value:2
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know the items on definition you can inline them like this:

```
var fs = {
    name:'test',
    items:[
      { name: 'item1', value: 1},
      { name: 'item2', value: 2}
    ]
};
```

Else you can use the Array push function.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fs = { 
    name:'test', 
    items:
    [
    {name:'item1', value:1},
    {name:'item2', value:2}
    ] 
};
```

Newline placement is arbitrary, of course.

Answer (score 0):

```
fs.items[0] = {
    name:'item1',
    value:1
};

fs.items[1] = {
    name:'item2',
    value:2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

or even ...

```
javascript:
var fs = {
    name:'test',
    items:[]
};

fs.items[fs.items.length] = {
    name:'item1',
    value:1
};

fs.items[fs.items.length] = {
    name:'item2',
    value:2
};
```

/*  and   */

```
alert(JSON.stringify(fs));
```

/*  displays   */

```
{"name":"test","items":[{"name":"item1","value":1},{"name":"item2","value":2}]}
```